# Discussion of LR(1) items: meaning?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lr-grammar

What is the canonical LR(1)  items ! I have read the Dragon Book, It confuses Me , (delta,gamma,toh,...)

Can Someone help me with this issue ?

What is this meaning in English? [A - > alpha.Bbeta , a]

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[A -> alpha . B beta , a]` basically means "assuming rule `A` was being expanded, so far we have seen `alpha`. We then expect to see `B beta`. We also know that after `A`, we are going to see an `a`"

So, in CLR(1), you have states consisting of some of these items. You then have many options:

- If the look-ahead (gamma) is a member of `first(B)`, and assuming you have a rule such as `B->gamma C`, then you can "shift" and go to a state containing `[B -> gamma . C, beta]`. As you can see, the `.` has moved passed `gamma` (because `gamma` is matched and the follow of `B` is `beta` because that's what came after `B` in the rule `A -> alpha B beta`.
- If the look-ahead is `a` and assuming `B beta` could generate `lambda` (empty string) (here, assume beta is a nonterminal that can generate `lambda`). Then, you can "reduce" and go to a state that contains rules such as `C -> something A . a something_else, follow]`. In this case, you have decided that the `alpha`, `B` and `beta` on the stack can be grouped into one `A`.

That was the simplest way I could explain this.

Comment: I am Iranian, and I have to admit I don't remember most of the terminology. What I do remember are: Look-ahead (next token in input), `first(A)` which in this case is `{alpha}` and `follow(A)` which is `{a}`. In fact, these three are what matters when writing a parser (and that's why I remember them). The rest is useful mostly when it comes to proving correctness of the parsing algorithm and other theoretical stuff.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, this is an "item", that is, the potential state of some sentential form parse.

What this means:

```
[A - > alpha.Bbeta , a]
```

is that when attempting to parse a (substring of the target language) which can be considerat as the nonterminal **A**, is the **alpha** has been seen, and (".") that **Bbeta** is expected next, and that if the elements of the nonterminal are seen, it is a valid **A** if the next token is **a**.

(I think you transcribed Bbeta wrong, it was probably beta in the book).

Comment: valid A means , we can reduce by A.